# Couldn't paginate properly using .skip().limit() mongoose method in express app

Tags: mongoose, pagination

I am trying to create a pagination using mongoose inbuilt .skip().limit() method in my express web app, but this isn't working fine for me. Whenever I try to switch to different page(page=2 or page=3) I get some collection(data) same as that of page 1, meaning I am not getting the different data while requesting different page. I am using "mongoose": "^5.13.3" version. The code looks like
**This inside asynchronous function**

```
const queryString = { ...req.query };

const excludeQueryString = ['page', 'sort', 'limit', 'fields']; 

excludeQueryString.forEach((el) => delete queryString[el]);

const queryObj = JSON.stringify(queryString).replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g,(match) => `$${match}`);

// QUERY
let query = Tour.find(JSON.parse(queryObj));

// 2. SORTING
if (req.query.sort) {
  const sortQuery = req.query.sort.split(',').join(' ');
  query = query.sort(sortQuery);
} else {
  query = query.sort('-createdAt');
}

// 3. LIMIMTING FIELDS
if (req.query.fields) {
  const queryFields = req.query.fields.split(',');
  query = query.select(queryFields);
} else {
  query = query.select('-__v');
}

// 4. PAGINATION
const page = req.query.page * 1;
const limit = req.query.limit * 1;
const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
query = query.skip(skip).limit(limit);

const tours = await query;

res.status(200).json({
  status: 'success',
  results: tours.length,
  data: {
    tours,
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you checked your query which is built after pagination? Try printing the query formed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
It's due to the `-createdAt`  that we sorted. If you change for the `_id` instead, there would't be any duplicate.

```
query = query.sort('_id');
```

(As we created the collection with copying a file at once, all `createdAt` timestamp are the same).